# Why some classes in Angular API documentation are marked abstract?

Tags: angular

**Why in [Angular.io/api](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#markForCheck) docs some classes are marked as `abstract`** (e.g. `ChangeDetectorRef`)

My question is not about the nature of '`abstract`' class in general, but rather on what Angular wants the framework user to consider, when they see '`abstract`' method in the API documentaion.

Usually '`abstract`' conveys "do provide implementation before use", BUT the class in the example can be DI injected and used - is this the idea ( '`abstract`', BUT available for direct use through Angular DI ) ?

If so, are all classes, which are marked as being 'abstract' in the documentation, available for direct use through Angular DI ?

```
// Ex.: ChangeDetectorRef   CLASS   STABLE

abstract class ChangeDetectorRef {
  abstract markForCheck(): void
  abstract detach(): void
  abstract detectChanges(): void
  abstract checkNoChanges(): void
  abstract reattach(): void
}
```

Comment: I guess the idea is to let the curious reader know that the method is abstract and thus that the concrete implementation must be found in subclasses, and that these implementations could have specificities. Abstract has absolutely nothing to do with DI. Your logic is as flawed as "the sea is blue, I can swim into the sea, does that mean that I can swim in everything that is blue?"

Comment: If this helps, the vb word for abstract is MustInherit, which gives a clearer idea that this class cannot function, and must be extended (inherited by another class) in order to actually function.